# Unable to override dependency in node

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, package.json

I want to upgrade dependency of one of the package include in a transitive way:

```
 minimist :: 0.0.8 >> node:npm:gitcorp/Myproject >> node:npm:artifactory/npm-dcloud:less:3.9.0 >> node:npm:artifactory/npm-dcloud:mkdirp:0.5.1
```

Package minimist should be update from 0.0.8 to 0.2.1.

I tried following approach

1.

```
node 8.1

     "scripts": {
      "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
    
    }
    {
      "resolutions": {
        "minimist": "0.2.1"
      }
    }
```

Still in my package-lock.json I see below:

```
  "mkdirp": {
          "version": "0.5.1",
          "resolved": false,
          "integrity": "sha1-MAV0OOrGz3+MR2fzhkjWaX11yQM=",
          "dev": true,
          "optional": true,
          "requires": {
            "minimist": "0.0.8"
          }
```

Secondly, when i run `"npm run build"` by ading above statements in my package.json, i get error as `npm ERR! missing script: build`

2. Since my node version is 8.1 so i cannot use overrides available in npm 8.3, as npm 8.3 requires node version 10+.

Is there a work around to force dependency version?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem. My problem was npm 8.1. I updated npm to, in my case, 8.7 and used the [override settings](https://%20https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) in the package.json e.g:

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "minimist": "0.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: txs @Tyler2P for pointing this out. I changed accordingly